# warp an input function with variadic-parameter into member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, variadic-templates

What I want to do is design a class that can execute a function asynchronously. I need warp it in member function, because I want to know whether it complete or not.

The basic design is the following:

```
struct SelectionAsynMission
{
    template<typename Function, typename...Args>
    void start(Function && f, Args&&...a)
    {
       // compiler failed here
       thread_.swap(thread(std::bind(&SelectionAsynMission::execute_warp<Function, Args ...>, this), f,std::forward<Args>(a)...));
      //thread_.swap(std::thread(f, std::forward<Args>(a)...)); no warp work fine
      thread_.detach();
    }
    template<typename Function, typename...Args>
    void execute_warp(Function && f, Args&& ... a)
    {
        thread_complete_ = false;    
        f(std::forward<Args>(a)...);
        thread_complete_ = true;
    }
    void join();
    atomic<bool>  thread_complete_; // Use atomic to tell the main thread whether it is complete.
    thread thread_;
};
```

The Compile Error is:
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

So any suggestion for the design to fulfill the requirement
Or ideas about fix the compile error would be helpful.

---

Thank you for your help, I was stupid enough to forget the basic of std::bind.

Before see your comments and answers

I have tried another way to do this. I use async to warp the function, and instead the atomic, i use future status to determine whether the job complete. I wasn't sure which cost more time, read atomic or future status, but the future status seems easier.

```
template<class Function, class...Args>
void start(Function && f, Args&... a)
{
    // start the function with async
    future_node_ = std::async(std::launch::async,f,std::forward<Args&>(a)...);
}

bool iscomplete()
{
    // wait for zero time to get status.
    auto status = future_node_.wait_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(0));
    // determine whether the job is done 
    return status == std::future_status::ready;
}
```

Comment: The result of std::bind doesn't take any parameters (yet you supply some) and the bind itself doesn't make sense given you're declaring what parameters are supposed to go in but not specify them. I don't think there is a pleasant way to work with std::bind in variadic templates and suggest that you use a mutable lambda instead.

Comment: The line that fails to compile is composed of a bunch of different nested statements, which of these exactly fails? Move each one to a separate line and store the result in a temporary for clarity. Also, please indent your code. That said, why do you store the thread in a member variable but detach the thread? That seems kind-of counterproductive. BTW: You need to set `thread_complete` to false before starting the thread, otherwise you don't know if the thread hasn't set it yet or whether it was already set to true.

Comment: You really need to be more consistent in your indentation and spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have kind of a skeleton of something usable. But the error is pretty obvious if you look where the error is coming from:

```
std::thread(std::bind(member_fn, this), fn, args...)
```

You're trying to pass arguments to a function object returned from a `std::bind` that doesn't take any arguments.

What you want to do is pretty hard using `std::bind`, because it requires the `std::placeholders` constructs `_1`, `_2`, `_3`, etc, etc to signal that there are `_n` many args to be passed. That would require some template trickery.

A better option would be to use a lambda expression; a feature of C++11, which you are probably using seeing as though you make use of `std::thread` which is another C++11 feature.

Here's how to do it using lambdas:

```
class myclass{
    template<typename Func, typename ... Args>
    void start(Func &&f, Args &&... args){
        m_thread.swap(std::thread{
            [this](Func &&f, Args &&... uargs){
                this->execute_warp(std::forward<Func>(f), std::forward<Args>(uargs)...);
            },
            std::forward<Func>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...
        });
        m_thread.detach();
    }

    template<typename Func, typename ... Args>
    void execute_warp(Func &&f, Args &&... args){
        m_thread_done = false;
        f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        m_thread_done = true;
    }

    void join(){
        while(!m_thread_done.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)){}
    }

    std::atomic<bool> m_thread_done;
    std::thread m_thread;
}
```

And I might add a way to do it using `std::bind` to my answer.